# How to overwrite GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in gcloud for python

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I was writing my Custom File Storage for Django using gcloud.

And have problems with gloud path where it looks for service account JSON.
I try to use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'google.json')
```

But it has no effect. It always looks for google.json in upper folder of my project (and it works fine if I put it there). I got this error:

```
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: File ../DjangoProjects/folder/google.json (pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!
```

so my project is in the `File ../DjangoProjects/folder/project_folder/google.json`

So, how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is supposed to have the name of an environment variable pointing to a file; it isn't supposed to have the file path itself. The default value of this variable is simply "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS". If you set an environment variable with the name GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path that you want it to use, it should work for you.

Comment: what are you trying to say as it looks like a non-sense

Comment: What he means is that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is an environment variable, not a Python variable. Try os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'google.json').

Answer (score 3):

This is just to clarify Garrett Jones' answer. There are some subtle confusions which can arise here:

In the code sample given, `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is a python variable name. Its *value* is supposed to be the *name* of an environment variable which points to the file:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
```

In this example, we assume there is an environment variable named "`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`" with its value being a file path (something like "`/home/anon/workspace/myProject/google_creds.json`")

Environment variables can be set in the environment using OS-specific means, or using python itself, which can modify the environment while the program is running (this is what Adam's comment on Garrett's answer is demonstrating, using `os.environ`).